# how to bind $index from ng-repeat to controller

Tags: angularjs

In Angular I wanted to bind $index to controller. How can I send $index value in to my controller. Here is my html code.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="demoController as demoCtrl">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="val in demoCtrl.list" >Hello {{$index}}</li>
    </ul>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller code

```
var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[])
app.controller('demoController', function(){
    var list = [1,2,3,4,5];
    this.list = list;

    var array = ['abc','def','ghi','jkl','mno']
    this.array = array
    console.log(this.array[index]);
});
```

I need to use ng-modal in HTML and bind that value to some variable in my controller.

Based on the selection of index, it should check in array and respective array should have to print.
Can any of you please help

Comment: When you have to use $index. On click or ?

Comment: Not on "On Click". I have modified the question. Please check once

Comment: `$index` is just the current iteration position in `ng-repeat`. *"I need to use ng-modal"* <- did you mean `ng-model`? *"Based on the selection of index"* <- what do you mean by *"selection"*? Can you give a simple example of what you want the end result to be?

Comment: I want to send the current iteration position to my controller and by using that position value I need to display array. If position =0, I need to display zeroth element in array. Yes It was ng-model. Selection in the sense for every li

Comment: there is `$index` which is available to you on your view. it starts from 0. If you want to start it from 1 onwards, one can use `{{$index+1}}` in the template. If you need to access it on your controller, you can do so by passing it from the view as follows `<li ng-repeat="element in list" ng-click="viewDetail($index)">{{element}}</li>`

Answer (score 2):

To get your current iteration position in your controller you have define a function.
So your html code like this.

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="demoController as demoCtrl">
    <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="val in demoCtrl.list" ng-click="dispArray($index)">Hello {{$index}}</li>
    </ul>       
    </div>
</div>
```

And your controller code

```
var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[])
app.controller('demoController', function($scope){
    $scope.dispArray = function(index){
          // console.log(index);
          // your code
    }
});
```

Comment: this gives me undefined every time.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish you might be better served creating a custom iterator.

```
function makeIterator(array){
    var nextIndex = 0;

    return {
       next: function(){
           return nextIndex < array.length ?
               {value: array[nextIndex++], done: false} :
               {done: true};
       }
    }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators

Angular is going to iterate over everything in the list when you use ngRepeat.  If you're trying to track which list item a user clicks then you'll just add that in there using $index.

```
<li ng-repeat="val in demoCtrl.list" > 
   <span ng-click="demoCtrl.userClicked($index)"> Hello {{$index}}</span>
</li>
```

If you're just trying to print the data in each item, ng-repeat is already iterating everything for you.

```
<li ng-repeat="val in demoCtrl.list" > 
   <span ng-click="demoCtrl.userClicked($index)"> Hello {{val}}</span>
</li>
```

It all depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't want to use "on-click". I have updated the question. Please check once

Comment: @YeshuAnnadata Are you just trying to print?

Answer (score 0):

i dont konw what u want to do. if u want to use event. you can pass $index to your controller function like:

```
    <li ng-repeat="val in demoCtrl.list" ng-click="getIndex($index)">Hello {{$index}} 

$scope.getIndex = function($index) {
console.log($index)
}
```

hope to help u.

Comment: I don't want to use on-click. I have updated the question. Please check once